# Python numpy bool masks for absoluting values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, masking

Suppose you have a numpy array(n,n) ie.

```
    x = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
```

and you fill x with random integers between -5 and 5. Is there a method to use a boolean mask so that all of my values which are 0 become 1 and all my numbers which are nonzero become zero?(i.e, if [index]>0 or [index]<0, [index]=0, and if [index]=0 then [index]=1)

I know you could use an iteration to change each element, but my goal is speed and as such I would like to eliminate as many loops as possible from the finalized script.

EDIT: Open to other ideas, as well, of course, as long as speed/efficiency is kept in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you could instantiate your array directly using [`np.random.randint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
# Note: the lower limit is inclusive while the upper limit is exclusive
x = np.random.randint(-5, 6, size=(5, 5))
```

To actually get the job done, perhaps type-cast to bool, type-cast back, and then negate?

```
res = 1 - x.astype(bool).astype(int)
```

Alternatively, you could be a bit more explicit:

```
x[x != 0] = 1
res = 1 - x
```

But the second method seems to take more than twice as much time:

```
>>> n = 1000
>>> a = np.random.randint(-5, 6, (n, n))
>>> %timeit a.astype(bool).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.58 ms per loop
>>> %timeit a[a != 0] = 1
100 loops, best of 3: 4.61 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you, this method worked in the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple comparison with `0` to give us a boolean array and then convert to `int` datatype with `+0` or typecasting with `.astype(int)`. Thus, we would have two approaches.

**Approach #1 :**

```
(x==0)+0
```

**Approach #2 :**

```
(x==0).astype(int)
```

**Runtime tests**

This section compares the runtimes for the earlier mentioned two approaches and includes the [`other numpy array based approach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656662/3293881) 
that converts `x` to boolean datatype -

Case #1:

```
In [36]: x = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

In [37]: %timeit (x==0)+0
    ...: %timeit (x==0).astype(int)
    ...: %timeit 1 - x.astype(bool).astype(int)
    ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.85 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 µs per loop
```

Case #2:

```
In [38]: x = np.random.randint(0,50,(10000,10000))

In [39]: %timeit (x==0)+0
    ...: %timeit (x==0).astype(int)
    ...: %timeit 1 - x.astype(bool).astype(int)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 227 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 186 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 319 ms per loop
```

It seems `(x==0).astype(int)` performs quite well!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension for this...

`bool_x = [0 if y != 0 else 1 for y in x.reshape(25,1)]`

If you are going for speed though consider if you really need the array to be 5x5, then converted, or if you could `np.arange(25)`, apply the list comprehension directly and then reshape. All that reshaping will cost you something surely.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to use reshape, you can create your random matrix directly like this:

```
M = np.random.randint(-5,5,(2,2))
```

Then if you want to do your substitutions you can just do your indexing like this:

```
M[M==1]=10
M[M==0]=1
M[M==10]=0
```